# Auto-focus and keyboard navigation in Vuetify <v-menu>

Tags: vuetify.js

Is it possible to auto-focus and allow navigation by keyboard in a ?

I want to be able to open the menu and have the 1st item focused and highlighted, and then for the user to be able to scroll up/down through the menu options.

VMenu supports the Keyable mixin, so the up/down arrows should be supported, but I can't figure out how to get it working

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference (`ref="yourMenu"`) to the VMenu component. After that you can call methods defined in keyable mixin, e.g.:

```
const menu = this.$refs.yourMenu
menu.changeListIndex(e)  // e is event that has brought you here
// or...
menu.onKeyDown(e)        // if you don't want to handle keys in different way
```